# Select prompt option disappears when validation fails in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, select, prompt

Let me preface by saying I'm a noob to Rails and StackOverflow so please go easy on me.  I'm using Rails 2.3.8 with sqlite3 on my dev box.

I have created a select pulldown in a form using the following:

```
<%= select( "communication", "gig_id", { "Add New Gig" => "new"}, {:prompt => "-- Select Gig --"}, :onchange => "toggle(this, 'gigInfo')") %>
```

However, when something else in the form fails validation and the "new" page is re-rendered, my prompt goes away and the only option left is the "Add New Gig" option.  This is the case with ALL my forms and I can't seem to find any answer as to why.

My controller uses the basic scaffolding so I'm sort of at a loss.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: using :prompt in your select helper disappears, but using :include_blank does not.  Switched those out and my prompt doesn't disappear anymore.

Answer (score 14):

Your observation is accurate, and you astutely observed that `:include_blank` remains even when `:prompt` does not.

You can achieve the results you want by setting `:include_blank` to the string you were using for prompt (it doesn't need to be a boolean).

`:prompt`, it seems, only appears when there is no value for Rails to supply the given field.  When your app re-renders the `new` view, there *is* a value to supply that field because it created an instance of your Communication model.  (It failed to save that instance, but it looks as though that instance has its `gig_id` field set.)