# Ruby on Rails and select tag :prompt value

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have an odd behavior of select tag. Here is a part of my code:

**controller**

```
  def edit
    @user = User.find(current_user.id)
  end
```

**view** (part)

```
=form_for @user
.field
  = f.label :gender
  %br
  = genders_select(f)
```

**helper**

```
  def genders_select(form)
    form.select :gender, [ ['Female','0'], ['Male', '1'] ], :prompt=>'select your gender'
  end
```

On `edit` action select doesn't have **prompt** value, it has 2 values: Female and Male. After I choose any value and press a button, 'select your gender' appears in it and an error "Gender can't be blank" also does.

Why is this happening and how do I solve it?

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue.  Use `:include_blank` instead of `:prompt`, i.e.,

```
def genders_select(form)
  form.select :gender, [ ['Female','0'], ['Male', '1'] ], :include_blank=>'select your gender'
end
```

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6474727/1938600) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

please try this, I think it will work

```
f.select(:gender, options_for_select(['male', 'female']), {:prompt => 'Select Gender'}, {:class => "form-control slct-box"})
```